# how to set jms broker using spring4 and ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I try to make example code to study jms. I got some error. So, i search some of articles for solving error. And I give up because i can't find how to set the broker in ActiveMQ using spring4. please give me some advice or solve the problem.

This is error.

```html
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.config.AppConfig.amqFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
 at kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.App.main(App.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.config.AppConfig.amqFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:195)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
 ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.config.AppConfig.amqFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1170)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:77)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:67)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:54)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.config.AppConfig.amqFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
 ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1199)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
 ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
 ... 55 common frames omitted
```

This is my spring configuration file.

```html
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Autowired
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqFactory;
//    @Autowired
//    CachingConnectionFactory cachingFactory;

    ...
    
    @Bean
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
//     String url = "tcp://localhost:61616";
     String url = "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false";
     ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
     return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> JmsContainerFactory()
    {
     SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(amqFactory);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(true);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

And, when i try to set CachingConnectionFactory that uses ActiveMQConnectionFactory, It bring error. however, in this site(http://shengwangi.blogspot.kr/2014/10/spring-jms-with-activemq-helloworld-example-send.html) it use two connection factory! Would you give me some advice and solve the problem?

---

-----------15, April------------------
When i adopt first answer, other error is occurs.
(I deleted state(factory.setConnectionFactory(amqFactory) in the method JmsContatinerFactory() and autowired variable )

This is error sentences.

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'amqConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [kr/ac/jbnu/sql/rded/config/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
 at kr.ac.jbnu.sql.rded.App.main(App.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
 ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your app config you are auto wiring the bean which you have not created yet. Try removing the auto wire piece from your app config and see if it works. Remove the below piece

Autowired
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory amqFactory;

Comment: In that case, should i create ActiveMQConnectionFactory in JmsContainerFactory()?

Comment: I adopt it, but i got other error. i edited my question

Comment: Oh, additional error is solved by adding port number in url, Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Wc glad I was able to help